# Text if range exists Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to test if a range exists to be able to create the following pattern:

```
if not exists(r) then
   MsgBox("Range is missing")
end if

Function exists(r as range) as boolean

End function
```

Here is an example of a range that I would like to test if it exists or not

```
Call RangeExists(lob.ListColumns("Leverera utt").DataBodyRange)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
Sub CheckRange()

    Dim myRange As Variant

    myRange = InputBox("Enter your name of your range")

           If RangeExists(CStr(myRange)) Then
                MsgBox "True"
           Else
                MsgBox "No"
           End If

    End Sub
```

And the function:

```
   Function RangeExists(s As String) As Boolean
        On Error GoTo No
        RangeExists = Range(s).Count > 0
    No:
    End Function
```

Comment: elegant function `RangeExists`

Comment: why don't you declare myRange as String directly? instead of entering a string in the inputbox, send it to myRange which is a variant and then convert it back to a string?! Uneccessairily complicated or do I miss something?

Comment: @Kathara It is because i used this code personnaly with an array and not with an Input box. That is true you can directly declare the input box as string. I did not change it because the most important was the function and not the Sub.

Comment: @manu aah, ok. Well then it's just nicer for the eye if you'd change it and it will probably be faster by 0.0000x seconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the label required in ON ERROR GOTO is also possible

`Function RangeExists(rngName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    RangeExists = Range(rngName).Column And (Err.Number = 0)
    Debug.Print "RangeExists= " & RangeExists & "   " & rngName
End Function`